# Implementation in R with RCPP

Tags: c++, r

I have written a brute force algorithm in R and it does work fine. I want to implement using Rcpp so that my code runs faster however I can't get it to work. for example for a simple example w = [4 2 3] , v = [10  7  4] with maximum weight W=5 it doesn't return the proper Value (11). I appreciate it very much if you could help me.
The Rccp code :

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;


//[[Rcpp::export]]
List brute_force(IntegerVector w, NumericVector v ,int W) {
  int n=sizeof(w);
  NumericVector result(0);
  int allCase =  static_cast<int>(pow(2, n));
  int maxValue = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < allCase; i++) {
    NumericVector temp(0);
    int currentCase = i, currentWeight = 0, currentValue = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
      if(currentCase&1){
        currentWeight+=w[j];
        currentValue+=v[j];
        temp.push_back(j+1);
      }
      if(currentWeight>W){
        break;
      }
      currentCase=currentCase>>1;
      if(currentWeight<=W&&currentValue>maxValue){
        maxValue=currentValue;
        result=temp;
      }
    }
  }
  List L=List::create(Named("value")=maxValue,Named("element")=result);
  
  return L;
}
```

value
20

element
2  3 11 12 13

the correct answer should be
Value 11
element 2 3

and My original R code is:

```
brute_force_knapsack= function(x,W){
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(x), apply(x, c(1,2), is.numeric), is.numeric(W), W>=0, colnames(x)==c("w","v"))
  n=length(x$w)
  w=x$w
  v=x$v
  result_elements=c()
  result_value=0
  range=1:2^(n) - 1
  for(j in range){
    element=which(intToBits(j)==01)
    total_weights=sum(w[element])
    total_value=sum(v[element])
    if(total_value > result_value && total_weights <= W){
      result_elements=element
      result_value=total_value
    }
  }
  result=list("value"=(result_value),"elements"=result_elements) 
  print(lengths(result))
  return (result)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
  int n=sizeof(w);
```

is bad because `sizeof` is not for obtaining number of elements but for number of bytes occupied on the memory.

It should be

```
  int n=w.length();
```